# C++ template argument inside template constructor

Tags: c++, templates

I have some templates and I want to add a constructor to Term that takes an Expr argument and saves it in a field variable in Term. How can I do that?

```
enum ExprType { mul, del, add, sub, expo};

template <ExprType t, int y, bool varFirst> class Expr {
    //....some code
};


template <int coeff, int power> class Term {
    // add constructor that takes instance of Expr and saves it in a field variable in the class Term
};
```

Comment: Expr is a template, you can't "save" it on a variable if it's not well defined on what that template should be instanciated, and so if you don't know that assign to "ExprType t, int y, bool varFirst"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, to make clarification, we must say that `Expr` is not a `type`, is `template`, so we can't treat it as a `type`. Firstly, `instantiation` should be made from the `template` to obtain a `type`. After this step, `Term` can take instance of the instantiated type from `template Expr`.

So possible implementation is below :

```
enum ExprType { mul, del, add, sub, expo};

template <ExprType t, int y, bool varFirst> class Expr {
    //....some code
};


template <int coeff, int power, ExprType t, int y, bool varFirst> class Term {

public: 

    using expr_t = Expr< t , y , varFirst>;
    Term( expr_t expr ) : m_expr { expr } {}

private:

    expr_t m_expr;

};

template<int coeff, int power , ExprType t , int y, bool varFirst>
auto make_term( Expr< t , y , varFirst > expr )
{
    return Term< coeff , power , t , y , varFirst >{ expr };
}

int main()
{
    Expr< mul , 1 , true > e;
    auto term = make_term<1 , 2>( e );
    auto term_2 = make_term<3 , 4>( Expr< mul , 1 , false> {} );
};
```

Comment: Is it not possible to pass an Expr instance to the constructor of Term?

Comment: @Parankush No it is not possible to take template as argument but you could take template as a template parameter.

Answer (score 0):

See this You may get an idea

```
#include<iostream>

template <class T>
class A                 
{
 public:
  T var;
  A():var{0} {}
  A(T i):var{i} {}
  A(A &ob):var{ob.var} {}
};

template<class T>
class B
{
 public:
  A<T> var;
  B(A<T> &ob):var{ob} {}
};

template <class T>
class BB
{
 public:
   T var;
   BB(T &ob1):var{ob1} {}
};

int main()
{
    A<int>      ob(100);
    B<int>     ob1(ob);
    BB<A<int>> ob2(ob);

   std::cout<<ob.var<<std::endl;
   std::cout<<ob1.var.var<<std::endl;
   std::cout<<ob2.var.var<<std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```